# from one file making multiple copies of a file with different names by using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i want to make 10 copies of a file named "as-1.txt" and want to get names of copied file as "as-2.txt" , "as-3.txt" and so on. for this shutil .copyfile() is not working in iterative condition with for loops

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Comment: There should be no problem with `shutil.copyfile`. Please tell us the error you get and show your code.

Comment: import shutil
for i in range (1 , 11): shutil.copyfile("as-1.txt", 'as-%d.txt' % i)

Comment: the code you have posted works unless you get an `IOError` because you are not in the directory that `"as-1.txt"` is

Comment: yes i got that now my own code is working i want to ask one thing more that in each copied file i want to change one line i.e, "gfileStart = 'init.in'" i want in as-2,txt this line should be as "gfileStart = 'init.in1'" and in as-3 file as init.in2 and so on ....

Comment: for i in range (2,11):
 shutil.copyfile("as-1.txt","as-%d.txt"%i)
 f=open("as-1.txt",'r')
 for line in f:
  if line.contains('init.in'):
   newline = line.replace('init.in', 'init.in%d'%i-1)
i have done this... and i do it by this way too 
for i in range (2,11):
 shutil.copyfile("as-1.txt","as-%d.txt"%i)
 f=open("as-1.txt",'r')
 f.find("init.in")
 f.replace("init.in", "init.in%d"%i-1)
but these both are not working what should i do

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess

for i in range(2,10):
    subprocess.call(['cp', 'as-1.txt', 'as-%d.txt' % i])
```